# Action column for a table in Angular not working

Tags: html, angular

So I am trying to add an Action column in may table. The other columns are received from an API. I don't know why is not working.
What are your impressions?

HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z2" *ngIf="show">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to Edit" class="iconbutton" color="primary">
                    <mat-icon aria-label="Edit">edit</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to Delete" class="iconbutton" color="warn">
                    <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns" [matColumnDef]="column">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{column}}</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; index as i;">
                <span *ngIf="element.editing; then editBlock else displayBlock"></span>
                <ng-template #displayBlock>{{element[column]}}</ng-template>
                <ng-template #editBlock>
                    <mat-form-field >
                        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="element[column]">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </ng-template>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

TS:

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["actions"];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
```

The call to get the table from the API:

```
  getTable(inputTable: string, inputFilter: string, inputValue: string) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.istManagementService.getGenericStaticTables(inputTable, inputFilter, inputValue)
    .pipe(finalize(()=> this.isLoading = false))
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.displayedColumns =  Object.keys(res.IstValues[0]);
      this.filters = this.displayedColumns;
      this.fieldsLocked = false;
      this.dataSource.data = res.IstValues;
      this.show = true;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Whay do you mean by `not working`?

Comment: you should "add" `actions` to your displayedColumns, e.g.: `displayedColumns=['id','name','actions']` and in the loop over displayed columns use a `*ngIf` to not use it -or take account when the columnName was "actions" and remove the `<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">`

Comment: @yurzui This new column named Actions is not showing

Comment: @Eliseo I don't understand exactly what I need to change... I also added the call, maybe there I am missing something

Comment: see where you write: `this.displayedColumns =  Object.keys(res.IstValues[0]);` you need write:`this.displayedColumns =  [...Object.keys(res.IstValues[0]),'actions'];`. But be carefully, because you're loop in the .html over displayedColumns. You need also check when column is or not 'actions'